# Enumerate printers on a Mac

Tags: c++, macos, printing

So, I'm familiar how to enumerate the printers using the Windows API, there are a ton of examples out there.

What I gathered from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60084/how-can-i-list-all-the-installed-printer-drivers-on-mac-os-10-6) is that I can find the printers in the `/Library/Printers/` directory.  When I searched there, I found more folders which didn't really mean anything to me.

To keep it simple, how do I query the mac to get a list of printers (local and networked) "attached" to the system?

Or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`NSPrinter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSPrinter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class (from the AppKit framework) provides information about all 
available printers on the system, for example

```
NSArray *printerList = [NSPrinter printerNames];
for (NSString *name in printerList) {
    NSPrinter *printer = [NSPrinter printerWithName:name];
    NSString *desc = [printer description];
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", name, desc);
}
```